# Cloud Endpoints, ServiceGenerator, OS X Mavericks issue

Tags: google-cloud-endpoints

I have been developing my iPhone app without trouble using GAE and Cloud Endpoints for the last month. :)

However, this week I updated my Mac OS to Mavericks. Without changing my code, I have been getting an error whenever I run the ServiceGenerator on my rpc discovery file now.

Below details the error log on bash: 
2013-10-26 21:49:50.740 ServiceGenerator[3979:507] 10.4-style NSDateFormatter method called on a 10.0-style formatter, which doesn't work. Break on _NSDateFormatter_Log_New_Methods_On_Old_Formatters to debug. This message will only be logged once.
Illegal instruction: 4

I am 99% sure this is a Mavericks upgrade induced error, and while I am trying to find a solution to downgrade back to Mountain Lion, I was curious if anyone had any temporary or quick fixes?

Thanks,
Mochi

Comment: Did you rebuild the generator before experiencing the issue? If not, can you try that?

Comment: Hey Dan, that was actually one the first things I tried. :( I reverted my OS back to Mountain Lion and everything is working fine for the time being..

Comment: Can you file a bug here? https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/issues/list (There's another bug mentioning Mavericks, but I think it's different.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have submitted the solution here:
https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/issues/detail?id=50

Hopefully svn is updated soon